# Bigquery Dynamic stored procedure

Tags: dynamic, google-bigquery

I am looking for Bigquery sample stored procedure which uses dynamic sql to create table using the sample data from below table. Stored procedure should accept two input parameter "DBname" and "Flag" and has to create multiple table dynamically. Please help with sample template of code to use. Thanks in advance.

DBname    TblName   FieldName   Datatype   Flag

DB2       Employee   ID           int       Y

DB2       Employee   Name         varchar   Y

DB2       HR         ID           int       Y

DB2       HR         Name         varchar   Y

DB2       HR         EmpID        int       Y

Teradata  Store      ItemNo        int      Y

Teradata  Store      ItemName      Varchar  Y

Oracle    Vendor     VndrID        int      Y

Oracle    Vendor     VndrName      varchar  Y